# Ecto delete many_to_many join whilst keeping joined records in tact

Tags: database, ecto, elixir

I have two Ecto models: `User` and `Skill`, which are joined with a `many_to_many` association via a `users_skills` table:

```
create table(:users_skills, primary_key: false) do
  add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)
  add :skill_id, references(:skills, on_delete: :nothing)
end

create unique_index(:users_skills, [:user_id, :skill_id])
```

In the `User` schema there is:

```
many_to_many :skills, Skill, join_through: "users_skills"
```

And in the `Skill` schema there is:

```
many_to_many :users, User, join_through: "users_skills"
```

What I want to do is delete a user’s skills without deleting the `User` or `Skill` itself. Currently I’m trying this:

```
query = Ecto.assoc(current_user, :skills)
Repo.delete_all(query)
```

However it throws the error:

```
(foreign_key_violation) update or delete on table "skills" violates foreign key constraint "users_skills_skill_id_fkey" on table "users_skills"
```

When adding `on_delete: :delete_all` to the `users_skills` migration, this has the undesired effect of deleting the associated skills.

How do I approach this so that only the association record is deleted with both `User` and `Skill` staying in tact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there're better ways to do this but you can pass `on_replace: :delete` option to `many_to_many` macro in your schemas.

```
defmodule User do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "users" do
    field(:name)
    many_to_many(:skills, Skill, join_through: "users_skills", on_replace: :delete)

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

Now if you run

```
current_user
|> Repo.preload(:skills)
|> Ecto.Changeset.change()
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:skills, [])
|> Repo.update!()
```

It deletes from `users_skills` table and `skills` table will remain intact.